# How to run a function once after element has been found with Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can run a function once after a specific element has been found?

I tried this:

```
setInterval(function () {
     if ($('.imagewrapper').length) {
            self.carousel();
     }    
}, 1000)
```

So, it checks my page continiously if the `.imagewrapper` element exisit, and if so, it should run the `self.carousel()`function. The problem is, that this way, as soon the element exists, it runs the function continiously. Is there a way around?

ps: The `setInterval`-method needs to be there.

Comment: `setInterval` has to be there and `callback` should not be executed after interval ?

Comment: @RayonDabre :  is your code syntax correct  , that `$(document.ready`?? and OP wants to run function again and again after a specified interval

Comment: @YoYo, No it is not! My comment was for _run a function once after a specific element has been found_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
(function delay() {
   if ($('.imagewrapper').length) {
       self.carousel();
   } else {
       setTimeout(delay, 1000);
   }
})();
```

or if you need setInterval:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('.imagewrapper').length) {
       self.carousel();
       clearInterval(interval);
   }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
// set ran to false when you load the page
ran = false;
setInterval(function () {
  // only do your stuff when you haven't do yet (ran==false)
  if (!ran && $('.imagewrapper').length) {
    self.carousel(); 
    // when you did it for the 1st time set ran to true, so next time you don't enter the if.
    ran = true;
} }, 1000)

// but even better to stop the timer after you entered the if for the 1st time:
timer = setInterval(function () {
  // only do your stuff when you haven't do yet (ran==false)
  if ($('.imagewrapper').length) {
    self.carousel(); 
    // when you did it for the 1st time delete the timer
    clearInterval(timer);
} }, 1000)
```

Comment: can you please explain your code and about `self.carousel(); `

Comment: I added comments. Caroussel comes from your code in the question, you should know it better what it is

Answer (score 1):

You looking for waitUntilExists https://gist.github.com/buu700/4200601
So, it will works something like that:

```
$(someselect).waitUntilExists(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    // do some code
})
```